# Is it possible to fall back to a global variable if it isn't defined in the local scope in a Twig template?

Tags: json, twig

Say I have following `_teaser.twig` partial:

```
<article>
  <h2> {{ article.headline }} </h2>
  <p> {{ article.lede }} </p>
  {% if {{article.byline }} %}
    <address>{{ article.byline }}</address>
  {% endif %}
</article>
```

Which i include these ways:

```
<aside>
  {% for article in teasrs %}
    {% include '_teaser.twig' %}
  {% endfor %}
</aside>
<section>
  {% for article in opinion.items %}
    {% include '_teaser.twig' %}
  {% endfor %}
<section>
```

With the following data structure in a `json` file:

```
{
  "article": {
    "headline": "A short headline",
    "lede": "A short descriptive lede paragraph"accusantium"
  },
  "teasers": {
    "article1": {
      "headline": "Some headline",
      "lede": "A lede that describes the article, but without revealing too much, so that users still have a reason to click"
    }, 
    "article2": {}
  },
  "opinion": {
     "article": {
       "byline": "Anonymous"
     },
     "items": {
       "article1: {},
       "article2: {}
     }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like the variable resolving to go up the scope, the same way it does in Mustache.

The desired output is:

```
<aside>
  <article>
    <h2> Some headline </h2>
    <p> 
      A lede that describes the article,
      but without revealing too much, so that 
      users still have a reason to click
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2> A short headline </h2>
    <p> A short descriptive lede paragraph </p>
  </article>
</aside>
<section>
  <article>
    <h2> A short headline </h2>
    <p> A short descriptive lede paragraph </p>
    <address>Anonymous</address>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2> A short headline </h2>
    <p> A short descriptive lede paragraph </p>
    <address>Anonymous</address>
  </article>
<section>
```

Unless I'm missing something, specifying the default using the `default()` filter isn't desirable, as I'd like the default content to be derived from the model, not the view. For instance, In the teasers, I don't want to have a fallback byline, but in the opinion section, I'd like to always show a byline, with a fallback to `Anonymous`, for which using `default` won't help with.

Answer (score 0):

*Use **default** pipe*

**doc** : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

```
<article>
  <h2> {{ article.headline|default('default value) }} </h2>
  <p> {{ article.lede|default('default value) }} </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks! I know the `default` filter, but I would like the default to be derived from the model not the view (i.e. from the `json` not the `twig` file). 

Ideally, I'd like the search to go up the scope, the same way it does in `mustache`. I'll update the question to represent this